# How to check RAM size?

Tags: ram

What is the command to find the RAM size in computer? I want to see result in MB.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

From a terminal you should be able to use:

```
free -m
```

From [`man` page](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html):

> `-m`, `--mebi` Display the amount of memory in [mebibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte).
>
> `--mega` Display the amount of memory in megabytes. [Implies `--si`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units).

**Note**: [A kilobyte (kB) is 1000 Bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte).

Comment: It's worth noting: `free -h --si` produces *human readable* output, in SI units of MB, GB, etc.

Comment: `free -h` will output it in human-readable output (usually GiB: Gibibytes--base 1024). But, since RAM is usually sold in GB (Gigabytes--base 1000), NOT GiB (Gibibytes), `free -h --si` is usually better, as @Jollywatt says, to output it in Gigabytes instead.

Answer (score 144):

Open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)...

Run following command to see RAM information in KB (1 KB is equal to 1024 bytes).

```
free
```

Run following command to see RAM information in MB (1 MB is equal to 1024 KB).

```
free -m
```

Run following command to see RAM information in GB (1 GB is equal to 1024 MB).

```
free -g
```

Or you can run following command to see more information about the same:

```
free -h
```

Comment: `free -h` seems most helpful to me. "all output fields automatically scaled to shortest three digit unit"

Answer (score 53):

Click on the power/gear icon (System Menu) in the top right corner of the screen and choose *About This Computer*. You will see the total available memory in *GiB*. Multiply the value by *1024* to get the size in *MiB*.

This value (and the value shown as *Total* in output of `free -m` on the console), is total physical RAM size, minus the amount assigned to the internal GPU, if your computer has one.

To see the total amount of physical RAM installed, you can run `sudo lshw -c memory` which will show you each individual bank of RAM you have installed, as well as the total size for the *System Memory*. This will likely presented as *GiB* value, which you can again multiply by 1024 to get the *MiB* value.

Comment: I'm going to upvote this just for the "sudo lshw -c memory" part, which is exactly what I needed..

Comment: `lshw -c memory` FTW!  run as root in RHEL 7.9 is states each installed ram dimm manufacturer (i.e. samsung) and serial number and dimm slot and clock speed and size in GiB.

Comment: the **`sudo`** for `lshw` is super **important** - otherwise you'll **NOT** get the actual physical state, the command warns you if you don't run it as superuser, but it's easy to overlook :-)

Answer (score 41):

Physical memory available in MiB:

```
echo $(($(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / (1024 * 1024)))
```

Virtual memory available in MB:

```
echo $(($(getconf _AVPHYS_PAGES) * $(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / (1024 * 1024)))
```

..or use /proc/meminfo:

```
grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2 / 1024}'
```

To see the physical chip information, you can use [`dmidecode`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode) to extract the DMI type 17 (*Memory Device*) tagged information:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 17
```

this informs you about all the memory devices installed, including the type, speed, manufacturer, form factor and a lot more besides. Yo also have `sudo dmidecode -t memory` which give a little bit more information.

Comment: With 1024 seems to be a [mebibyte (MiB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte), no MB.

Comment: Upvoting for the `grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo`, which works great via ssh.