# How to Check How Much Ram

Tags: ram

How do i view how much ram is installed on my PC 
It's supposed to be 8GB but with a command i tried it says 6GB ram and 2GB swap file

```
            total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        6111392     1968428     1709540       60312     2433424     3794260
Swap:       2097148           0     2097148
```

Comment: See https://vitux.com/5-ways-to-check-available-memory-in-ubuntu/  Which command did you enter? Please copy what you typed in to run it and what appeared on the screen as a result; click [edit] and paste that into your question. Please don't use Add Comment; please instead use [edit].

Comment: Ok i have done that. Thx

Comment: You haven't given us much information about your physical system? Is it a laptop? Desktop? Some server you're ssh'ing into? Why are you assuming it should be 8Gb? My answer and K7AAY's link are more than plenty for you to find the total memory on your system

Comment: It said 8GB DDR4 Ram when i purchased it, just a desktop

Comment: @venomx Please also run `awk '/MemTotal/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo` and add it into your question with [edit]. TY for what you've done so far.

Comment: Going by what I posted from the terminal in my original post do I have 8GB?

Comment: Ok I looked into the machine and the brand of ram I have only come in 8GB, 16GB, 32GB, 64GB SO it can't possibly be 6GB. Im guessing 6GB is being used for Ram and 2GB for my swap file

Comment: I did that command and it says " 6111376 "

Comment: search for `Memory:` in /var/log/kern.log. That line will tell you how memory is allocated at boot time. See also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621255/why-does-the-system-report-7-7gb-of-total-ram-when-i-installed-8gb/621271#621271).

Comment: How many memory modules do you have on your motherboard?

Comment: two slots, so must be 2x4GB as they don't come any smaller

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check RAM size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898941/how-to-check-ram-size)

Answer (score 4):

To view how much ram your system has, you can use the `free` command

```
[sol Build]$ free -h

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       3.0Gi       6.5Gi       842Mi       6.0Gi        11Gi
Swap:         8.0Gi          0B       8.0Gi
```

if you're interested, you can also check out whats going on in `/proc`

```
cat /proc/meminfo
```

or to get the total *physical* ram installed in the system

```
awk '/MemTotal/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo
```